# get the href of one link and put it in the href of another link

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, href

I'm trying to grab the href of one of my links and clone/copy that to the href of another link

Here's what i'm trying

```
      var link = $('.topbook');
      var link2 = $('.sidelink');
      var hrefOrig = link2.href;
      link.href = hrefOrig;
```

Thanks

Jamie

**UPDATE**

Here's is what I'm trying to get

```
<a href="default.aspx?propid=BARN" class="topbook"></a>
```

The above link should clone the sidelink that has display:block

`<a href="default.aspx?propid=FARM" class="sidelink" style="display:none"></a>`

`<a href="default.aspx?propid=BARN" class="sidelink" style="display:block"></a>`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks that works - bit of a problem is there any way to say get the href of the ".topbook" button that has the style ="display:block" property? As i have 10 buttons with the class ".topbook" and only want to get the href of the button that is showing. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) like this:

```
 var link = $('.topbook');
 var link2 = $('.sidelink');
 var hrefOrig = link2.attr('href');
 $(link).attr('href', hrefOrig);
```

You can make it shorter like this:

```
$('.topbook').attr('href', $('.sidelink').attr('href'));
```

### Update

To get the `href` of visible elements, you can use the `:visible` filter selector like this:

```
$('.topbook:visible').attr('href', $('.sidelink').attr('href'));
```

This will apply the `href` to those elements that have class `topbook` and are visible/showing.

Comment: @Jamie Taylor: Can you elaborate exactly what are you expecting?

Comment: @Jamie: Try this: `$('.topbook').attr('href', $('.sidelink:visible').attr('href'));`

Answer (score 0):

It is by the way much faster if you use $() with tag names, as this query can be internally optimized via document.getElementByTagName()

```
var link = $('a.topbook');
var link2 = $('a.sidelink');
link.attr('href',link2.attr('href'));
```

and if you even know, that there is only one link each:

```
var link = $('a.topbook:first');
var link2 = $('a.sidelink:first');
link.attr('href',link2.attr('href'));
```

Comment: Thanks that works - bit of a problem is there any way to say get the href of the ".topbook" button that has the style ="display:block" property? As i have 10 buttons with the class ".topbook" and only want to get the href of the button that is showing. Thanks